# Hadoop :No space left on device

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am getting the below exception in hadoop, while running some tasks.
But HDFS shows that it has space.
Any info regarding this error would be helpful.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device 
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:270) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:506) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:447) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) 
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262) 
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No space left on device 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.write(RawLocalFileSystem.java:220) 
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65) 
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$Positio
```

Comment: I deleted all the contents of the /tmp directory. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your logs are not rotated. Please check directory: /var/log/ it has directory hadoop*. It may got filled completely and its not finding place to store logs.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is space on HDFS, some of the nodes might have their disks full. You can check that from the web UI of DFS, by selecting the Live Datanodes.